# Character Creator in Javascript

Tags: php, javascript, jquery

I've had an idea for a website and would like a character creator.

One that has options for different eyes, mouth, hair, etc.

Then the options the person has chosen be submitted to their wordpress account photo.

What would be the best way to pull this off?

Any help is greatly appreciated! :)

Thanks

Comment: too vague, you should ask about a certain feature you need help on, and give example code.

Comment: I don't have example code, I've looked everywhere for something similar but nothing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming that all you need to do is overlay the pieces, you could simply have a bunch of `img` elements absolutely positioned within a container, and when the user selects a different thing for a particular part, you can change the appropriate `img`'s `src`. When they want to apply it, you can send what they selected for each thing and PHP can use [the GD image functions](https://www.php.net/manual/en/ref.image.php) to composite the pieces on the server side and use that as the account image.

Comment: Or he can also use canvas. ;)

Comment: @Derek: If he wants to restrict use of it to browsers that support `canvas`.

Comment: ...or use [Raphaël](http://raphaeljs.com/)...

Comment: @YanickRochon: That would work too, but I don't think it would significantly simplify the code that would have to be written, would it? Besides, that would pull in another library, of which only a small portion would be used.

Comment: @icktoofay, I agree. The `img` superposition would probably be as simplistic as things could be. However, if a more "flexible" solution would be envisioned, where vector graphics would be involved, instead of overloading a server with mindless tasks that the browser can do itself, Raphaël is a cross-browser solution that would work (espacially instead of hand coding a not-so-well-supported canvas solution) :)